# Binding.scala: Vars.bind seems to not work correctly

Tags: binding.scala

Calling `.bind` on a `Vars` in a watched `Binding` definition leads to strange behavior. The new binding is updated only once at init time but not after updating the `Vars` content.

For example, if I do this:

```
private val test: Vars[Int] = Vars(1,2,3,4)
Binding(test.bind match{case newd => println("TESTS DATAS has changed: " + newd)}).watch
test.value.append(1111)
```

Then, I got a single output line (while I should get two):

> TESTS DATAS has changed: Buffer(1, 2, 3, 4)

See this scalafiddle for a complete working example:
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/0PkkLPE/1

I tried different options like transforming to a `Binding` first with `.all` but that does not change anything. Maybe, I did not understand something with `Vars` but that doesn't look very consistent with `Var`for which it works well.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Feel free to create an issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it was a bug but I  was not sure...so I will open an issue for it.